# What is the best Monero-mining program for MacBooks?

Tags: mining

I have an old 2012 MacBook Pro and an 2018 Macbook laying around. Is there a program or a Tool which make it possible for me to use them for Mining?

The specs are, my 2012 has 16GB Ram and a 2,7GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, the 2018 one has 32GB of Ram and a 2,9GHz 6-Core Intel core i9 processor.

I would be glad for any type of help.

K_goerbi

Answer (score 1):

[XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) runs on Apple machines fine.

Comment: Big thanks for your comment. Right now I tried the entire day to Install XMrig ... do you have an tutorial in form of an blog or an video who to install it properly?

Comment: It's not exactly hard. Download it (or build), create your [config](https://xmrig.com/wizard) and run. Lot's of info/links at [xmrig.com](https://xmrig.com/) and on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/)

Comment: which pool would you recommend?

Comment: One that's near to you, has features you like... Please try to avoid asking subjective questions on StackExchange, see https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for guidance. Thanks.